# 64bit MFC ActiveX control in 32bit Application

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a situation where I have to create an MFC ActiveX control and use it in IWS(Indosoft Web Studio). As IWS is 32bit application so I have to provide a 32bit ActiveX control but I am using 3rd party libraries and all of them are 64bit so I cannot compile a 32bit control. 
Is there any way that I can use the 64bit control in some sort of service and use it in IWS. Remember there is no way that i can compile a 32bit control and there is no 64bit IWS.

Comment: Install older version of MS VC++

Comment: I tried that too. It does not work. The 3rd party libraries depends on hardware drivers and those drivers no more supporte the current hardware.

Comment: You cannot use a 64 bit DLL in a 32 bit application (and vice versa). An OCX is just a DLL.

Comment: I know that. There is a way "out of process com component", the idea is that 32bit and 64 bit dll can't run in the same process but i am struggling to find a working example or something that i can use as a reference.

Comment: [link](http://www.dllwrapper.com/dllwrapper_home.htm)  something like this.

Comment: I am trying [this](https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/#more-355). I guess it is the answer to my question. I will update once i confirm it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible in principal with such a solution. But I would expect a big pain with it and maybe only partial success. Good luck and yes, please, keep us informed!